# How to detect printer out of paper in OS X?

Tags: macos, printing

In Mac OS X: Is there a programmatic way to detect if the selected printer is out of paper?

Comment: that would presumably be printer specific?

Comment: Don't know, in Windows there are generic ways to query printer status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Mac OS X uses [CUPS](http://www.cups.org), and that provides a printer-agnostic API.

See the API documentation, particularly [table 1.1](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html#PRINTERS_AND_CLASSES) which details amongst other things error conditions